# Get full list of Facebook Graph API Results

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to get a full list of Graph API Results. Right now I'm just using the Graph API explorer and it automatically paginates my results.

If I were to write an application in, say, PHP to execute graph API queries, would I be able to get a full set of the results in JSON? I recognize that the result-set may be massive.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `limit` parameter, but there's no way to turn off pagination entirely. The maximum `limit` is typically 100 (but this can very from endpoint to endpoint).

The PHP SDK has built-in support for handling the paginated responses to collect a larger result set, but attempting to retrieve hundreds of pages at once will likely run you up against rate limits.

Comment: How would you handle paginated response to collect a larger result-set?